# Separate channels in java

Tags: java, audio, wav

This software records sounds of PC (with targetdataline) but I can't separate both channels (stereo) in Java...

For exemple: I connect to my PC one ipode and one iphone with one audio cable (stereo) ipode is on the right channel and iphone on the left channel. So I want to be able to record the right channel or the left channel. For the moment when I record I have the two sounds on the same audio file.

My AudioFormat

```
float sampleRate = 8000.0F; // 8000,11025,16000,22050,44100  int
sampleSizeInBits = 16; // 8,16  int channels = 2; // 1,2 boolean
signed = true; // true,false  boolean bigEndian = false; // true,false
return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels,
  signed,bigEndian);
```

And write my file with "TargetDataLine" For exemple :

```
targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);  
targetDataLine.start();
AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine), fileType,
  audioFile);
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you post details about what you've tried? Code snippets?

Comment: My AudioFormat  `float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
  // 8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
  int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
  // 8,16
  int channels = 2;
  // 1,2
  boolean signed = true;
  // true,false
  boolean bigEndian = false;
  // true,false
  return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
    bigEndian); `

Comment: And write my file with "TargetDataLine"                                                           For exemple :                                                                                                    `targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
targetDataLine.start();
AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine), fileType,
    audioFile);`

Comment: Please update the question - comments can be deleted. I'm just trying to help you formulate this in a way that is more likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set channels=1 on your targetDataLine and use it to read data on a particular channel. Whenever you need the audio on a particular channel, you can know what to read based on where the info is being read from. Keeping your audio data in a byte[] will be most appropriate as you can select what data is being read from the byte[]. I suggest you look through sound.sampled again and decide how to deal with it. I am having problems with my system mic, i would have looked at this code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you must use the read                                 ( int read(byte[] b,  int off,  int len)method of targetDataLine right?

Comment: but I doubt you would have been able to use an example?